# ¿ Como sumar un año a una fecha que se ingrese en un input date en Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tengo un input tipo date, quiero que al actualizar la fecha que esta arriba se actualize también el de abajo y se sume un año.
tengo esto pero suma la fecha actual al entrar pero no al actualizar el input.

```
    $scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision = new Date();
    $scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Vencimiento = new Date(new Date().setYear($scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision.getFullYear() + 1));

   <tr>
       <th>Fecha de Emisión</th>
         <td><input class="form-control" style="width: 30%;border: 2px solid #ccc;" type="date" ng-model="datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision" />
         </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Fecha de Vencimiento</th>
         <td>{{datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Vencimiento}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es usar la directiva [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). Cuando el usuario cambia el campo, esta directiva evalúa la expresión de manera inmediata (a diferencia de JavaScript puro que evalúa el cambio cuando el usuario pulsa <kbd>enter</kbd> o el campo pierde el foco).

Entonces la idea sería hacer lo siguiente:

- Añadir la directiva `ng-change` al input de emisión para controlar el cambio
- Crear una función en el `$scope` que controle el cambio, y en dicha función:

  - Leer el valor del campo de emisión
  - Calcular un año más de esa fecha
  - Asignar la nueva fecha al campo de vencimiento

Aquí dejo una demo de cómo funciona `ng-change`:

> Nota: soy principiante en AngularJS, y no sé exactamente cómo trabaja con fechas, así que seguramente el código de abajo es una auténtica barbaridad. No lo tomes como referencia, es sólo una demostración de cómo funciona `ng-change`

```js
angular.module('app', [ ])
       .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  // crear los valores de las fechas
  $scope.emision = new Date();
  $scope.vencimiento = new Date(new Date().setYear($scope.emision.getFullYear() + 1));

  // dar formato a las fechas
  $scope.emision.fecha = $scope.emision.toISOString().slice(0,10);
  $scope.vencimiento.fecha = $scope.vencimiento.toISOString().slice(0,10);

  // controlador del cambio de valor en emision
  $scope.cambioFecha = function() {
    // actualizar los valores de las fechas
    $scope.emision = new Date($scope.emision.fecha);
    $scope.emision.fecha = $scope.emision.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    $scope.vencimiento = new Date(new Date($scope.emision.fecha).setYear($scope.emision.getFullYear() + 1));
    $scope.vencimiento.fecha = $scope.vencimiento.toISOString().slice(0,10);
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <table ng-controller="ctrl">
    <tr>
      <th>Fecha de Emisión</th>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="emision.fecha" ng-change="cambioFecha()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Fecha de Vencimiento</th>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="vencimiento.fecha" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Señor Alvaro. me sirvio el codigo que me proporciono, era justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer con un **[`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)**.

La ventaja inmediata es que si cambias el valor de `$scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision` mediante javascript `$scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Vencimiento` también se actualiza.

Si usas [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) este no ejecutará el código si ocurre lo siguiente

- Si el valor retornado por las transformaciones de los `$parsers` no ha cambiado
- Si el input continúa siendo inválido
- Si el modelo ha sido cambiado mediante código y no por un cambio al input

Por eso te recomiendo que sólo uses `ng-change` si y sólo si se cumplen las dos condiciones

- Nunca modificas esos valores por código
- Tienes puesta alguna validación algo compleja en tu `ng-model` (ej. `ng-pattern`) y solo quieres ejecutar el cambio cuando el valor es válido.

Este plunker demuestra el problema http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRU0H5?p=preview

Este código es más que suficiente

```
$scope.$watch('datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision', function(val) {
    if (val) {
        var nuevoCarnet = $scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet;
        var emision = new Date(nuevoCarnet.Emision);
        nuevoCarnet.Vencimiento = new Date(val);

        nuevoCarnet.Vencimiento.setYear(emision.getFullYear() + 1);
    }
});
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ChangeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.datosNuevoCarnet = {
      NuevoCarnet: {
        Emision: null,
        Vencimiento: null
      }
    };

    $scope.$watch('datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision', function(val) {
      if (val) {
        var nuevoCarnet = $scope.datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet;
        var emision = new Date(nuevoCarnet.Emision);
        nuevoCarnet.Vencimiento = new Date(val);

        nuevoCarnet.Vencimiento.setYear(emision.getFullYear() + 1);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChangeCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision">
  <h2>Valor introducido</h2>
  {{datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision}}
  <h2>Fecha vencimiento</h2>
  {{datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Vencimiento}}
</div>
```

Aún mas simple si no pretendes usar el valor `Vencimiento` en código y nada más usarlo de manera informativa puedes usar un `filtro` para formatear la salida

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ChangeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.datosNuevoCarnet = {
      NuevoCarnet: {
        Emision: null
      }
    };
  })
  .filter('vencimiento', function() {
    return function(input) {
      if (input) {
        var date = new Date(input);
        date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
        return date.toString();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChangeCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision">
  <h2>Valor introducido</h2>
  {{datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision}}
  <h2>Fecha vencimiento</h2>
  {{datosNuevoCarnet.NuevoCarnet.Emision | vencimiento}}
</div>
```